# Changing of degrees

Tags: degree-of-comparison

Consider this sentence:

> This is the best book I have ever read.

Now if I transform this into a sentence and use positive degree as

- Never have I read a book as good as this.

Is this sentence correct and complete or do I have to add 'one' at the end? Then the sentence would be

- Never have I read a book as good as this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["This one is" OR "This is"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287050/this-one-is-or-this-is). In 'this one', 'this' is used as a demonstrative (proximal) 'determiner'/'determinative', singling out _which_ one. But _this_ works just as well on its own, and its part of speech here is demonstrative pronoun. Look these up in a dictionary.

Comment: More succinctly, and without the "poetic / literary" deviation from normal English word order, ***I have never** read a book **this good***.